# Order of Constants TS in Template Analyzer

Tags: typo3, typoscript

i'm struggeling with the order of typoscript in constants. I've a provider extension holding all the templates and files for the site. Typoscript ist used in external files, i don't want to store typoscript in the database. I use typo3_forum ext and want to modify the templates to customize it. But when i put the ts for the view like:

```
plugin.tx_typo3forum {
view {
   templateRootPath = EXT:provider/Resources/Private/Templates/Forum/Standard/
   partialRootPath = EXT:provider/Resources/Private/Partials/Forum/Standard/
   layoutRootPath = EXT:provider/Resources/Private/Layouts/Forum/Standard/
 }
}
```

these values will be overwritten by the typo3_forum ext itself, cause the constants of typo3_forum ext stands in the templateAnalyser hirachy under my provider extension.
Sure storing the above ts in the constants field of my roottemplate solves the problem but is there no solution for external fiels to sort?

I've tried:

```
plugin.tx_typo3forum.view.templateRootPaths.100 = EXT:provider/Resources/Private/Templates/Forum/Standard/
```

but this doens't work, the ext uses the default template in that case.

Thanks for your help!

Cheers  Mark

Comment: How do you include the TypoScript of typo3_forum? Via "Include static" or in your provider extension?

Answer (score 0):

Put your line

`plugin.tx_typo3forum.view.templateRootPaths.100 = EXT:provider/Resources/Private/Templates/Forum/Standard/`

in the setup, not in constants.

You can move the path to constants like

Constants:
`plugin.tx_typo3forum.view.myTemplateRootPath = EXT:provider/Resources/Private/Templates/Forum/Standard/`

Setup:
`plugin.tx_typo3forum.view.templateRootPaths.100 = {$plugin.tx_typo3forum.view.myTemplateRootPath}`

If using TYPO3 version 8, take a look at https://forge.typo3.org/issues/75862. There is a bug regarding the fallback for template paths. The issue has been solved already and is targeted for version 8.4

Comment: Do you mean in the setup field of the root template in Database? Is there no chance to put in the setup.txt of my provider ext?

Answer (score 0):

The order of TS appearing in the template analyser simply reflects the order in which the files are loaded.

If you are already using a provider extension for your TypoScript and don't put any TS statements in the database (which is a good practice) you can go one step further and put no extension TS in the database at all (not even include static templates in the template record).

Just include the TypoScript files that you need in your provider extension with `<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT` and you have complete control of the order of things.

In the database you have to put just one line in constants and one in setup, each of the including from your provider extension. This will also make you less dependent of the database because if you include a new file it is just loaded and no actions are needed in the actual template record in the backend.

Comment: Hi Daniel, so do i. My external ts files are grouped in modules in separate folders like config and so on. The setup.txt file of my provider ext includes all the TS external files with <INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT and this file is included on the roottemplate (static from extension). But there is the problem. So i putt the above code to set the template path in an external file. Cause the vendor extension, for which i wanna change the template path, is loaded after my provider extension the pathes will be overwritten. Is there any solution?

Comment: If you include all TypoScript (even from vendor extensions) in your provider extension (and in your provider extension only!) you do not have this problem.

Comment: Understood, but the vendor extension includes the ts by itself. Cause this ext is loaded after my provider, the path is overwritten.

Comment: How does the vendor extension includes its TS?